# BMI Calculator displaying result in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So I am writing a BMI calculator and displaying the user's BMI works well however I'm having a hard time getting javascript to display the meaning of their result. After the user enters their height and weight and press the **assessBMI** button, their numerical BMI value appears, but how can I include the **conclusion** variable that determines what range they fall in? Everything else is fine, except connection their result with their numerical output. Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> function assessBMI() {
var heightInInches = document.getElementById("height").value;
var weightInPounds = document.getElementById("weight").value;
var calcBMI = Math.floor((weightInPounds * 703) / (heightInInches * heightInInches));
var conclusion;
document.getElementById("BMI").value = calcBMI;
document.getElementById("result").value = conclusion;

switch (calcBMI) {

       case (calcBMI < 18.5) :
           conclusion = 'You are underweight';
           break;
       case (calcBMI > 18.5) && (calcBMI < 24.9) :
           conclusion = 'You fall within the average range';
           break;
       case (calcBMI >= 25) && (calcBMI < 29.9) :
           conclusion = 'You are overweight';
           break;
       case (calcBMI > 30) :
           conclusion = 'You are obese';
           break;
 <input type="button" value="assessBMI" onclick="assessBMI();">
```

Comment: Just use good old `if`s, `switch` isn't the best fit for the task. Your comparisons actually have several holes: 18.5, 24.9, 29.9, 30.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `document.getElementById("result").value = conclusion;`, `conclusion` is still undefined. You have to set that value **after** your switch statement.

Note that you are missing a closing bracket at the end of the switch block, that may mess with your code. Should end up looking like so:

```
switch (calcBMI) {
   // cases
}

document.getElementById("result").value = conclusion;
```

Answer (score 1):

It might improve the organization if you created a separate function that takes a `BMI` input and returns a "conclusion". So `assessBMI()` might end up like this:

```
function assessBMI() {
    var heightInInches = document.getElementById("height").value;
    var weightInPounds = document.getElementById("weight").value;
    var calcBMI = Math.floor((weightInPounds * 703) / (heightInInches * heightInInches));
    document.getElementById("BMI").value = calcBMI;

    document.getElementById("result").value = bmiConclusion(calcBMI);
}
```

Then you can focus on figuring out the BMI range. Probably the simplest method would be just a series of `if...else` statements:

```
function bmiConclusion(bmi){
    if(bmi <= 18.5)
        return 'You are underweight';
    else if(bmi > 18.5 && bmi <= 24.9 )
        return 'You fall within the average range';
    else if(bmi > 24.9  && bmi <= 30)
        return 'You are overweight';
    else if(bmi > 30)
        return 'You are obese';
    else
        return '';
}
```

You could use a `switch` statement, but I don't think it makes the code any more readable or manageable:

```
function bmiConclusion(bmi){
    switch (true) {
        case (bmi <= 18.5) :
            return 'You are underweight';
        case (bmi > 18.5) && (bmi <= 24.9 ) :
            return 'You fall within the average range';
        case (bmi > 24.9 ) && (bmi <= 30) :
            return 'You are overweight';
        case (bmi > 30) :
            return 'You are obese';
        default:
            return '';
    }
}
```

It actually makes the code longer, plus you end up with that odd `switch (true)` statement.

Comment: Thank you so much. You're right using the if else statements worked better.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code; I've fixed the holes and have also moved `document.getElementById("result").value = conclusion;` to the end. I hope this is what you needed.

```
function assessBMI() {
    var heightInInches = document.getElementById("height").value;
    var weightInPounds = document.getElementById("weight").value;
    var calcBMI = Math.floor((weightInPounds * 703) / (heightInInches * heightInInches));
    var conclusion;
    document.getElementById("BMI").value = calcBMI;

    switch (calcBMI) {

       case (calcBMI < 18.5) :
           conclusion = 'You are underweight';
           break;
       case (calcBMI >= 18.5) && (calcBMI < 25) :
           conclusion = 'You fall within the average range';
           break;
       case (calcBMI >= 25) && (calcBMI < 30) :
           conclusion = 'You are overweight';
           break;
       case (calcBMI >= 30) :
           conclusion = 'You are obese';
           break;
    }

    document.getElementById("result").value = conclusion;

}
```

Comment: `switch (calcBMI)` <-- how do you think: what does it mean? And how it is comparable with `calcBMI < 18.5`?